# How can I fix "cracks" in 3d model?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, three.js, blender

I used a laser scanner to create a 3D model, and I'm trying to show it on webapp using three.js.

The model looks fine when I load it on Blender or Unity but it shows some cracks in both webapp with threejs and 3D viewer ( default windows application )

How can I fix these cracks?

I exported the data model as glb and obj file format, but both of the format had the same result.

(model on 3D viewer)

[image]

(model on blender )

[image]

( Texture Image )
[image]

Comment: Do the "cracks" disappear if you switch to nearest texture filtering? Try setting the `minFilter` and `magFilter` properties of the texture to `THREE.NearestFilter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for those who run into the same issue. I tried this code while loading GLB file which already contains texture.

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

// model
var model, mat, geo;
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    "https://xxxxxx/model.glb"
    // called when the resource is loaded
    function (gltf) {
       model = gltf.scene;
       model.traverse( function( object ) {            
           if ((object instanceof THREE.Mesh)){ 
                mat = object.material;
                geo = object.geometry;
                mat.map.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
                mat.map.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
           }
       });
       scene.add(model);
    },
    // called while loading is progressing
    function (xhr) {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function (error) {

        console.log('An error happened');
        console.log(error);

    }
);
```